# Jetpack CSS .screen-reader-text breaks mobile menu

Tags: themes, mobile, plugin-jetpack

`button.screen-reader-text.font-secondary` on https://www.evwe.ch is not visible thanks/due to the Wordpress Jetpack CSS `.screen-reader-text` definition.

Hence, the menu is not visible on mobile devices. Apparently the theme I use is not able to deal with that.

Is there are way to turn off that Wordpress Jetpack behavior or overwrite it?

Answer (score 2):

You can:

- Setup a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) and override the screen-reader styles using a more specific CSS rule
- Setup a child theme and override the header / menu and remove that css
  class
- Try and see if there is a hook to allow you to change the markup for this button (you may need to contact the author of your theme)